# JS Jsonpath query on object atttibute

Tags: javascript, expression, jsonpath

with to https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath im trying to do a path query on

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [ 
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      }, {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      }, {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      }, {
         "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  }
}
```

to check if a bicyle with color red exists

```
"//store/bicycle[color='red']"
```

would be the xpath equivalent for defiant.js and its works for me. i can not make out how to translate this expression to jsonpath? all my expression to make a == search on an array of objects work but direct object access somehow not. any ideas?